# Password Requirements Complexity - Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, javascript, security, password

I would like to increase password security for customer and admin accounts in Magento. In addition to minimum password length, contain **uppercase**, **lowercase**, **special characters**, and **digits**.

I found the JavaScript file that controls the validation. Path:js/prototype/validation.js (Screenshot and code attached)
What is the appropriate code to be added?

[image]

```
 ['validate-password', 'Please enter 8 or more characters. Leading or trailing spaces will be ignored.', function(v) {
            var pass=v.strip(); /*strip leading and trailing spaces*/
            return !(pass.length>0 && pass.length < 8);
        }],
['validate-admin-password', 'Please enter 7 or more characters. Password should contain both numeric and alphabetic characters.', function(v) {
            var pass=v.strip();
            if (0 == pass.length) {
                return true;
            }
            if (!(/[a-z]/i.test(v)) || !(/[0-9]/.test(v))) {
                return false;
            }
            return !(pass.length < 7);
        }],
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use below regular expression.

```
(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$/)
```

Explanation of this expression is

```
(/^
(?=.*\d)                //should contain at least one digit
(?=.*[a-z])             //should contain at least one lower case
(?=.*[A-Z])             //should contain at least one upper case
[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}         //should contain at least 8 from the mentioned characters
$/)
```

You can replace line

```
 return !(pass.length>0 && pass.length < 8);
```

with

```
if (!(/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]{8,})$/.test(pass))) {
        return false;
}
return true;
```

And change error message related to expression. You can do same for admin password.

For special character you can use below regular expression.

Minimum 8 characters at least 1 Uppercase Alphabet, 1 Lowercase Alphabet, 1 Number and 1 Special Character from amongst these $@$!%*?&#^ .

```
"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])([A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&#^]{8,})"
```

You can use it like this way

```
if (!(/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&#^])([A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&#^]{8,})$/.test(pass))) {
     return false;
} 
return true;
```

Comment: Thank you Akhilesh. How can we incorporate the special characters as well?

Comment: I have edited my answer for special characters.

Comment: Thanks bro! Take my Upvote!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please note that if you wish to use the "Send Auto Generated Password" found in the customers admin page you will need to update the "generatePassword" function found in "app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php". Obvs, copy this file to the local folder before making changes. This is the code that I am now using for this function:

```
public function generatePassword($length = 14)
    {
        $char_upper = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');
        $char_lower = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');
        $char_num = array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');
        $char_special = array('$','@','$','!','%','*','?','&','#','^');
        $chars_new = array();

        shuffle($char_upper);
        $char_upper_rand = array_rand(array_flip($char_upper), 2);
        $chars_new = array_merge($chars_new, $char_upper_rand);

        shuffle($char_lower);
        $char_lower_rand = array_rand(array_flip($char_lower), 8);
        $chars_new = array_merge($chars_new, $char_lower_rand);

        shuffle($char_num);
        $char_num_rand = array_rand(array_flip($char_num), 2);
        $chars_new = array_merge($chars_new, $char_num_rand);

        shuffle($char_special);
        $char_special_rand = array_rand(array_flip($char_special), 2);
        $chars_new = array_merge($chars_new, $char_special_rand);

        shuffle($chars_new);
        $final_chars = implode($chars_new);
        return Mage::helper('core')->getRandomString($length, $final_chars);
    }
```