# How to apply simpler password constraints for customers in magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, magento-2.1, password, rules

When setting up a new password, a customer may read the following message :

`Minimum of different classes of characters in password is 3. Classes of characters: Lower Case, Upper Case, Digits, Special Characters.`

I understand it's a good thing in terms of security, but I think this is way too much complicated for customers, and that it may prevent some of them to create an account at all.

Is there a way too apply simpler password constraints for customers ?

Comment: This gonna help http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117449/magento-2-change-password-length-validation
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84205/password-requirements-complexity-magento

Answer (score 7):

Thanks Ankit Shah,

Solution here : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/141422/43576

"As of version 2.1.1 this is a configuration item. In Stores > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Password Options there's some options like Password Length and Number of Required Character Classes. Not sure at which version this was introduced but if you update your store to the latest version it will be available."